# Write string to remote file using libssh2

Tags: c++, string, ssh, scp, libssh2

I'm try to use libssh2 to write a string to a file. And I can do it.

The problem is I only can write once to the file, I can't append to the file, and giving the arguments to the `libssh2_scp_send` I give the size, if the size is bigger then the real size of the string (ex. I give 50, but the string have 5 chars) the is created but with 0 bytes.

function I use:

```
int s7c_hardware::writeKey(char * filename, char * str)
{
    channel = libssh2_scp_send(session, filename, 0777, strlen(str));
    char buf[99999];
    memcpy(buf, str, strlen(str));
    buf[strlen(str)] = '\0';
    libssh2_channel_write(channel, buf, strlen(str));
    libssh2_channel_free(channel);
    channel = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the `memcpy()`? Isn't the effect exactly what `strcpy()` does? When do you close the channel? Because `channel` seems to be a global variable ... and I see no calls to [libssh2_channel_close](https://www.libssh2.org/libssh2_channel_close.html). Is there an error returned from the channel write (you ignore it).

Comment: @dhke Sorry, I forget to put the code to close the channel. Why memcpy? because in my app that string can have "\0" zero terminator in the middle.

Comment: You should use the SFTP protocol rather than SCP if you can. SCP isn't very sophisticated.

Comment: @Kenster But the difference between SCP and SFTP is: SCP is faster, don't use ACK flag, but with SFTP you can start and stop your download our upload

Comment: @Kenster But ok, I will try to use SFTP

Comment: If your string may contain null byte `\0` in the middle, `strlen()` is not the right function you need.

Comment: @alvits So what I use to have the size of a string with `\0` in the middle?

Answer (score 1):

Now I understood the why! SCP cannot append to a file because that's literally starting and stoping the download and SCP cannot do that, but SFTP can!